# Запуск locationManager из службы

Tags: android, gps

Этот код в Activity работал нормально. 
Создал в приложении службу, перенес код в нее, и он перестал работать. Сама служба стартует и работает. Чего ей не хватает?

```
public class LocService extends Service {

private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Запустить поток в фоновом режиме для обработки.
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            1000, 50, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            1000, 50, locationListener);

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Код в данном месте не вызывается ни при каких обстоятельствах
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Не тем пользуетесь. Используйте http://habrahabr.ru/post/191290/

Comment: @Andreich, стоит также учитывать [#57880. Google Play services out of date](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880) Баг тянется больше года, касается не только AVD, но бывает (сам столкнулся тоже) и реальных устройств.

Comment: Переписал код с использованием 

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

Работает как часы, хоть и стал несколько сложнее...